# Drawing string doesn't work

Tags: c#, drawing

I'm trying to draw text on a bitmap which is then shown in a picture box. Code is the following:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("filename.bmp");

        RectangleF rectf = new RectangleF(70, 90, 90, 50);

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        g.DrawString("myText", new Font("Tahoma", 8), Brushes.Black, rectf);

        g.Flush();

        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
    }
```

When I run the program and press the button2 I get an error.
It says:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
>
> Additional information: Incorrect parameter.

I can't find any mistake there. What could be wrong?

Comment: On which line you get this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify an existing file name. The more flexible solution is to just specify dimensions of your bitmap. For example, next code creates a text in a bitmap

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(200, 200);

//your code

bmp.Save(@"D:\filename.bmp");
g.Flush();
```

creates next image at `D:\filename.bmp`

[image]

If you want to **alter** existing bitmap by adding new text, use `Image.FromFile` method, like:

```
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"D:\filename.bmp");
```